# OpenGL3.3:glGetMultisamplefv is giving invalid value

Tags: opengl

My Code is :

```
   glGenFramebuffers(1, &_hFBO);
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &(_hRender[colorAttachment]));
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _hFBO);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, _hRender[colorAttachment]);
    glRenderbufferStorageMultisample(GL_RENDERBUFFER, samples, format, width, height);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 +colorAttachment,GL_RENDERBUFFER, _hRender[colorAttachment]);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
    glGetMultisamplefv(GL_SAMPLE_POSITION, p_index[0], val);


where,
Samples =4
format=GL_RGBA
width=height=512
p_index[0]=1

In this ,it is  giving me GL_INVALID_VALUE for glGetMultisamplefv. 

Note: If I call glCheckFramebufferStatus before attaching default frame buffer object (glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0)) also, then it  is not giving any error.
```

Does it necessary to  check glCheckFramebufferStatus before attaching default FBO.?

Comment: Is your default framebuffer multisampled? Since you're binding the default framebuffer before calling `glGetMultisamplefv()`, the call will get the sample position from the default framebuffer, not the FBO you just created. Also, I believe `glRenderBufferStorage()` might need a sized format. Try `GL_RGBA8` instead of `GL_RGBA`.

Comment: @RetoKoradi  I am calling default FBO as  glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);. I am not sure how to make it multisampled please let me know how to do.No luck with sized format

Comment: Let me try and explain what I mean as an answer. Not totally sure if it's what you're looking for, but it sounds like it might be.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the `glCheckFramebufferStatus()` call should not make a difference at all. It only checks the status of the current framebuffer, and returns either `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE` if the framebuffer is ok, or one of various possible error codes otherwise. Since you're not looking at the return value, the call does not serve any purpose in your code fragment.

The way I understand your code, you're trying to query the sample positions of the multisampled FBO you just set up. But that's not what the code is doing. Since you bind the default framebuffer before the `glGetMultisamplefv()` call, the query would apply to the default framebuffer. Since your default framebuffer is not multisampled, that will give an error.

The main thing you need to do is rearrange the sequence of some of the calls, primarily to call `glGetMultisamplefv()` while your new FBO is bound:

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &_hFBO);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _hFBO);

glGenRenderbuffers(1, &(_hRender[colorAttachment]));
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, _hRender[colorAttachment]);
glRenderbufferStorageMultisample(GL_RENDERBUFFER, samples, GL_RGBA8, width, height);

glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + colorAttachment,
                          GL_RENDERBUFFER, _hRender[colorAttachment]);
if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
    // we got a problem
}

GLint sampleCount = 0;
glGetIntegerv(GL_SAMPLES, &sampleCount);
if (sampleCount == 0) {
    // we got a problem
}

for (int sampleIdx = 0; sampleIdx < sampleCount; ++sampleIdx) {
    GLfloat val[2] = {0.0f, 0.0f};
    glGetMultisamplefv(GL_SAMPLE_POSITION, sampleIdx, val);
}

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

I would also change the format of the renderbuffer to `RGBA8`, since the `internalformat` for `glRenderbufferStorage()` is normally supposed to be a sized format.

BTW: Starting variable names with an underscore is not recommended. Names starting with an underscore are reserved for internal use by the compiler and standard libraries.